# Making an image have a link

Tags: php, hyperlink, href

I`m new to this website and I was hoping to get my first question out and get some feedback on my issue.

I am creating a "slider" which you can find here: http://complusoft.net/demo-catarroja2/es/ (at the very beginning of the page) and i`m trying to make the images which pass through the slide to be a link.

Here you can find the code which I have done:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item):  ?>
        <?php if($params->get('itemImage') && isset($item->image)): ?>
            <a class="moduleItemTitle" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $path1;?>?src=<?php echo $item->image;?>&w=635&h=386&zc=1&q=100" alt="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>" title="#htmlcaption<?php echo $key;?>"/>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item):  ?>
    <div id="htmlcaption<?php echo $key;?>" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <?php if($params->get('itemTitle')): ?>
        <!--<h2><a class="moduleItemTitle" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a></h2>-->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="clr"></div>
        <?php if($params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>
        <div class="description-slider2">
            <p><?php echo $item->introtext; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ive looked around the internet and besides my own knowledge I know this should be the correct way besides the point that this is simple HTML I believe, I may be wrong please correct me if so.

Comment: Where are your <a> tags pointing to? As in, they are echoing PHP elements but those elements need to be links to where every you want to go. You may also want to end the <a> tags as well.

Comment: The <a> tag was ending at the end of the image, I have edited anyways for being easier to view :).

Comment: Thanks :) So, where is the link pointing to? Do you have the php echoing the specific location in the "href" section?

Comment: I have edited the question, please recheck to see where the links go to.